How Can we resize the Chakra Select Option Width?
Basically i want to resize the chakra Select box options. i found this is a SLOT badge in elements.

i have tried multiple option. but none of the worked

first i was try with basic CSS Property,

{
    background: red;
    width: 50px;
    max-width: 50px;
}

as we can see, only color property applied.


i also tried with :slotted. but looks like it is not working as expected.

select.\:\:slotted\(option\) {
    max-width: 50px !important;
    width: 50px !important;
    background: green;
    display:flex;
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    color:yellow;
}

option:slotted(option){
 max-width: 50px !important;
    background: red;
}


the issue is, it is going to outside of its width


The dropdown width cannot be set.
It's width depends on the option values
The Browser controls how the options looks like.
You can use Select2 https://select2.org
